# Cantrips at higher levels

Tags: dnd-5e, cantrips

**Specifically from a roleplaying perspective, how does learning cantrips at higher levels make sense?**

They are described as spells you know so well that you can cast them at will. Given that you learn them at higher levels, how would a character have been practicing it so much that they can cast it at will, when they couldn't cast it at all?

My only thought is that they learn the cantrip as a subsidiary of higher level spells, and you effectively learn how to constantly cast a weaker version of your upper level spells, but you're given the option of the whole cantrip list, so maybe this isn't right.

Comment: So, to clarify, you are asking us to explain how new cantrips are learned narratively? You are not looking for a rules explanation?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If the rules offer a narrative/roleplaying perspective,  I must have missed it.

Comment: @SteveBauer [Please don't answer in comments.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments) Rule of thumb: if you're trying to seek clarification or more information from the question, it belongs in a comment; if you're trying to help provide movement toward a solution it belongs in an answer and not a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New cantrips, spells and other class features don't often come with a ready explanation for how a PC gained them.

For many players this is perfectly fine as they don't want to or do not think to justify their character's constant growth in capacities. For cases when a player does care about these justifications, they can be worked into the story with varying degrees of DM involvement and player roleplay.

In the case of a cantrip, a player could for instance:

- Simply state that their PC has finally gotten the hang of this new cantrip they've been practicing for months in their downtime, rests and travels.
- Go further down that road by planning their new cantrip ahead of time and roleplaying practicing it when appropriate.
- Work with the DM to include the cantrip's acquisition into the story through an event of some kind or during extended downtime.

Long story short, it's up to a player or play group to decide how much attention they want to pay to these details.

Answer (score 1):

D&D 5e explains the mechanics of spell casting but has little in the way of theory. It is left to the referee of a campaign to explain why magic works the way it does.

For example in my Majestic Wilderlands setting. I explain it like this.

> Spells work through memorization of techniques that allow the caster
>   to create a Form with their will. The Form is held within the mind
>   until needed. The caster calls it forth and channels the local mana
>   into the Form which creates the effect of the spell. After the effect
>   is released both the mana and Form dissipate and the caster has to
>   spend time to recreate the Form.
>
> Wizards create their Forms through reading and performing the required techniques from a
>   spellbook. Their training and skill, as represented by their level determines how many Forms can be
>   created and held at any one time.

What this boils down is that the number of spells a magic user can memorized is a result of mental discipline supported by the meditation, and study technique the magic user master through learning. The reason a higher level caster can cast more cantrip is that through practice and study they can internalize more of the needed elements to cast cantrips.